# Round robin array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, round-robin

I am trying to make an round robin array. If I were to feed this array a bunch of values in a loop and I hit the end of the array (let's say it is 10 in length), how would I loop around to the first index?

Comment: You mean a circular-queue?

Comment: *Modular* algebra should help out you: `myArray[index % myArray.Length];`

Comment: Google for circular buffer should help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When looping, use *modular algebra* to compute array's index:

```
   myArray[index % myArray.Length]
```

Sample

```
  int[] myArray = new int[10];

  // Round robin feeding; trying to put 0, 1, .. 13 into int[10]:
  for (int i = 0; i < 14; ++i) // note 14 > 10 
    myArray[i % myArray.Length] = i; // i % myArray.Length - modular arithmetics

  // Test
  // 10, 11, 12, 13, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
  // note that first 4 values (10, 11, 12, 13) are overriden
  Console.Write(String.Join(", ", myArray));
```

Comment: Excellent. Simple and elegant. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can turn your array into a never-ending stream, e.g.:

```cs
public static IEnumerable<T> RoundRobin<T>(T[] input)
{
    while (true)
    {
        foreach (T item in input) yield return item;
    }
}
```

This allows you get one value at the time and continue doing this as long as you need, e.g.:

```cs
public class Batman
{
    private IEnumerator<int> stream;

    public Batman()
    {
        int[] values = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55 };

        this.stream = Helper.RoundRobin(values).GetEnumerator();
    }

    public int GetNext()
    {
        this.stream.MoveNext();
        return this.stream.Current;
    }
}
```